# Date validation with html5 dates

Tags: javascript, beginner, strings, datetime, html5

This code validates the following:

- `enddate` should not be less than or equal to `startdate`.
- `startdate` should not be less than or equal to the date today unless `document.getElementById("ltype").value == "1"`.
- The maximum gap between `startdate` and `enddate` is one year, more than that should cause an error alert.

Please review my code. I think I covered all test cases, but I am extremely new to JavaScript, so this code might have bugs. And is it fine to compare dates as strings? I did this because as far as I know HTML5 date is a string.

```
// creates a date object then converts it to a string with yyyy-mm-dd format
function dateFormat(date, addyear) { // addyear is boolean, true means add another year to the date
    var dd = date.getDate();
    var mm = date.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    if (addyear) {
        yyyy++;
    }
    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 
    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 
    return yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
}

function date_compare() {
    var today = dateFormat(new Date(),false);
    // from and to are html5 date fields
    var d1=document.getElementById("from").value;
    var d2=document.getElementById("to").value;
    var startdate = dateFormat(new Date(d1),false);
    var enddate = dateFormat(new Date(d2),false);
    var yeardate = dateFormat(new Date(d1),true);
    if (enddate <= startdate || enddate > yeardate) {
        alert("Dates out of range");
        return false; 
    }
    if (document.getElementById("ltype").value != "1" && startdate <= today) {
        alert("Error! date goes backwards!");
        return false;
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Instead of giving your variables names like `dd`/`mm`/`yyyy`, you should give them names like `day`, `month`, `year`. Other names like `d1` or `d2`. Should have better names.
2. You need some space between operators. For example, you have this condition in your code: `if(dd<10)`. Stuff like this can be expanded to `if(dd < 10)`. Variable definitions should also not look like this: `var x=...;`, but rather, `var x = ...;`.
3. You should add some more comments, e.g, describe what the functions/code blocks do, and how the processes behind them work.
4. Finally, just a small nitpicky thing. Both of your functions should be in `camelCase`. One of them is in `underscore_case`.